# Powershell Select- String and Invoke Command

Tags: command-line, bash, powershell

I am using `Select-String` to get a computer name from file. Then use the `$computername` on the `Invoke Command -ComputerName $computername -Scriptblock{...}.`

The problem is that, I get an error `"Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty."`

When I echo `$computername`, I get the computername value. Where am I going wrong?

e.g:

```
$computername =  $filename | select-string "server = " | %{$_.line.split('server =')}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername  -ScriptBlock{...}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUSer. We'll need more code to figure out where things go wrong. For example what is $filename?

Comment: try this >>> `'server = 123456'.Split('server = ')` <<< and then tell me how many blank lines you see before the `123456` ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you, it was the blank space, I have trim() the variable.